# mozart-stdlib : Depends: mozart (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable

Tags: apt, software-installation

On a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 system I am trying to install the Mozart (http://www.mozart-oz.org/) programming environment. Unfortunately I got the following error message reporting missing dependencies.

```
>> sudo apt-get -f install mozart mozart-doc mozart-stdlib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mozart-doc is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mozart:i386 : Depends: emacs23:i386 or
                        emacsen:i386
 mozart-stdlib : Depends: mozart (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this issue ?

My `sources.list` file's content (not modified since fresh installation)

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

Answer (score 2):

First try to install emacs23 by using `sudo apt-get install emacs23:i386` then re-run that command.

Please make sure you don't have any PPAs that might contain versions of packages that doesn't fit the dependencies.

Comment: I already tried that but it failed with: 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs23:i386 : Depends: emacs23-bin-common:i386 (= 23.4+1-4ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libm17n-0:i386 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libotf0:i386 (>= 0.9.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: @ManuelSelva look at the new paragraph.

Comment: first, thanks for your help. I unchecked all "Other Sources" in Software Sources app (I guess this app modifies apt sources.list files) and tried again to install either emacs23:i386 or mozart but I still get the smae problem.

Comment: @ManuelSelva post your /etc/apt/sources.list into your question please.

Comment: Done (question edited)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo aptitude install mozart mozart-doc mozart-stdlib`.

Aptitude will attempt to find solutions which may involve modifying other packages. It may give you more explanation of the problem and options for fixing it.

Comment: Unfotunately it doesn't solve the issue and the only thing aptitude proposes is to keep actual package configuration (meaning not installing anything)